# pascal triangle program displaying wrong output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pascals-triangle

I have designed a program that takes user input for each number in a number triangle and displays to the console whether it is a pascal triangle or not. The problem is that the code keeps displaying that the number triangle isn't a pascal triangle when it is. I'm just wondering what could be causing it to keep displaying "It is not a pascal triangle" even when it is. Thank you.

```
def checkIfPascal(dataLines):
    size = int(dataLines[0])


    n = 2 * size + 1
    grid = [[0 for x in range(n)] for y in range(size)]

    left = 1
    # do not read first line
    for i in range(size, 0, -1):
        parts = dataLines.split(' ')
        count = 0
        for p in parts:
            grid[i - 1][left + 2 * count] = int(p)
            count += 1
        left += 1

        # if there are not n+1 numbers, then it is not pascal
        if (count != i):
            return False

    left = 1
    for i in range(size - 1, -1, -1):
        if i == 0:
            return (grid[i][left] == 1)
        numbers = i + 1
        count = 0
        while count < numbers:
            current = grid[i][left + count * 2]
            upperLeft = grid[i - 1][left - 1 + count * 2]
            upperRight = grid[i - 1][left + 1 + count * 2]
            if (current != (upperLeft + upperRight)):
                return False
            count += 1

        left += 1
    return False


# main function



dataLines = input("please enter the height: ")
rows = int(dataLines) # --> convert user input to an integer
def triangle(rows):
    PrintingList = list()
    for rownum in range (1, rows + 1): # use colon after control structure to denote the beginning of block of code
        PrintingList.append([]) # append a row
        for iteration in range (rownum):
            newValue = input("Please enter the next number:")
            PrintingList[rownum - 1].append(int(newValue))
            print()

    for item in PrintingList:
      print (*item)
triangle(rows)

def main():
    if checkIfPascal(dataLines):
        print('It is a pascal triangle')
    else:
        print('It is not a pascal triangle')

main()
```

when the user inputs a number triangle that is a pascal triangle, it should display 'It is a pascal triangle' to the console

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete disaster of not testing your code as you build.  Let's look at how the program starts:

```
dataLines = input("please enter the height: ")
rows = int(dataLines)

triangle(rows)

def main():
    if checkIfPascal(dataLines):
        print('It is a pascal triangle')
    else:
        print('It is not a pascal triangle')

main()
```

The user's triangle, as read in by `triangle()` is printed and thrown away!  We then call `checkIfPascal()` on the unconverted *string* version of the height of the triangle, not the triangle itself!

And `checkIfPascal()` is it's own swamp of code.  Although the `triangle()` function appears to format the data as a `list` of `list` of `int`, `checkIfPascal()` is calling `split(' ')` on its argument as if it's composed of strings!  The two functions don't agree on their shared data structure.

Start small and test as you go.  Don't write the entire program and assume you (or we) can simply debug into working.  I think it's a cool idea for a program.